# Cannot load VSTO deployment file for Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to install an Outlook plugin that was developed using C# on .Net Framework and was published using click once manifest.
However i am getting below error whenever i try to install the vsto file .
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, i cleaned and rebuilt the solution but the plugin did not load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming VSTOInstaller.exe.config file to VSTOInstaller.exe.config.bak because I believe VSTO Installed does not require the config file.

Comment: Thanks @georgyfelix_w ,this fixed the problem .